# Success button is inactive bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

is there any way that a **bootstrap** success button will look like same as a **success** button but it will be **inactive**.

The problem is when i make the **success** button **inactive** it change the color of a **success** button, looks fade, so it doesn't fullfill the requirement of a success button.

Anyone knows how make an success button inactive.

Comment: What is the current code that you are using for the buttons?

Comment: how you are making it inactive?

Comment: You can do this of course, but I fail to see why do you want this.

Comment: can you please specify whether you want the success button not to perform any activity or in looks perspective?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inactive"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your button :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Save changes</button>
```

Your css :

```
.btn[disabled]{
  opacity: .65;  //Comment this
}
```

Comment: By the way `disabled="true"` is incorrect. `disabled` is a boolean property, `disabled` and (in case of XML notation) `disabled="disabled"` is correct.

Comment: Of course it does, that does not make it correct.`disabled="false"` works too, it just does not do what you would expect :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by overriding the Bootstrap CSS:

```
.btn-success.disabled, .btn-success[disabled] {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The original value is `.65`, which makes the button greyed out.

But this way, all success buttons will look the same. Which is confusing for the user, and *this is bad* from an UX standpoint.